# What BigO time complexity is my function?

Tags: ruby, substring, big-o

What is the BigO classification for this function?

Problem definition: You have an array of integers and you want to find the largest contiguous (together in sequence) sub-sum. Find the sums of all contiguous sub-arrays and return the max.

I'm still a little more than 7 months into programming, so I want to try to argue that even though there are nested loops that this function is still O(n) time complexity. The nested loops aren't going over the same data twice, they're pushing one time through a single set of data in tandem (I'm aware that I'm most likely incorrect about this). Is my intuition wrong on this? And why?

```
def largest_contiguous_sub_sum(arr)
    largest_sum = -100

    (0...arr.length).each do |start_idx|
        (start_idx...arr.length).each do |end_idx|
            current_sum = arr[start_idx..end_idx].sum
            largest_sum = current_sum if largest_sum < current_sum
        end
    end
    largest_sum
end

arr = [2, 3, -6, 7, -6, 7] #=> 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigO isn't about the data you are going over it is about how you iterate through that data. I see three primary loops:

- 0 to N as x
- x to N as y
- x to y as z

Looks like O^3 to me.

Comment: the array sum is hiding that third inner loop, which is why that's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understand this a little better now.

Answer (score 2):

> The nested loops aren't going over the same data twice

They absolutely are. Not even twice.

First iteration of the inner loop is from 0 to N. Then from 1 to N. Then from 2 to N. N iterations in total. This makes it O(N^2). And that's only the explicit loops, not including the actual logic, which has another linear scan.

> that even though there are nested loops that this function is still O(n) time complexity

This is trivial to prove. Measure the time your function takes to run on an input of length N. Then measure on length of 10*N. If it has linear runtime complexity, the second time it'll run only 10 times slower. But in this case, the performance hit will be... more pronounced.